# How to use this.$notification of Ant Design (Vuejs) in .js file?

Tags: vue.js

Actually we use this.$notification.open(opitons) in .vue file then it will show the notification in our web app. But How can we use this.$notification.open(options) in .js file. for example, I write the external function in .js file and it will show the notification if there is an error. I have tried to import Antd then use Antd.notification.open(opens). this code doesn't work.

Ant Design Notification link is here: https://www.antdv.com/components/notification/

Comment: Are you also importing vue into your js file?

Comment: No, I don't.
Now, I try to use it in main.js file

Answer (score 0):

You can import the notification from ant design directly on .js files
eg

import { notification } from 'ant-design-vue';

notification.error({
message: 'Error !',
description: err.response.data.message,
class: 'error'
})